# How to retain a value set in javascript after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following problem. I have a page and in the `Document Ready` event I call a web service that returns a string value. After that the value is assigned to a Label control (visible). After that I want to use the value in the Code Behind but I don't know how to get it.

All the events `Page_load`, `Page_Prerender`, ... have passed before the value has been retrieved from the service so I can't get it in any of them.

If I try to get it on a button click the page does a postback and loses the value.

I tried to find the control via `Request.Form` but it still returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ValueOFWebService = "sss";
    $('#hf').val(ValueOFWebService);
});
```

ASPX:

```
<input id="hf"  runat="server" type="hidden" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(hf.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change value of `label` at client side but you will not get new value of label at server side because it is not editable. you can put `hidden field` for that an get value of that.

Comment: you will never get new value , because at server you will get old value.You can set label's value only at server side ,not at client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can save value in Hidden Field

Aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="CustomHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

In code behind file :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "someval=" + this.CustomHiddenField.Value, true);
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var value= someval;
$('#htmlemement').val(value);
```

});